# Bootstrap tabbing red underlining not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create a tablayout in bootstrap that looks like the ones in android.

I am trying to create these tabs like they explain here:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-line-tabs-by-keenthemes

But I want to use bootstrap 4.0.0. My code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3y2wgsao/1/

css:

```
/***
Bootstrap Line Tabs by @keenthemes
A component of Metronic Theme - #1 Selling Bootstrap 3 Admin Theme in Themeforest: 
Licensed under MIT
***/

/* Tabs panel */
.tabbable-panel {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Default mode */
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a > i, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open .dropdown-menu, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a > i {
  color: #404040;
}
.tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.portlet .tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tabbable-panel">
                <div class="tabbable-line">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 2 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 3 </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
                            <p>
                                I'm in Tab 1.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 2.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Click for more features...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 3.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the red line doesn't change to the active link. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Whats the issue here ?

Comment: This answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594048/8270343 shows how to make it work along with a handy code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the CSS selectors now that the `active` class is applied the anchor instead of the `li` in Bootstrap 4...

https://www.codeply.com/go/xV3CvpV2yy

```
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li a:not(.active):hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li .active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes in the HTML and CSS.

See if my developed fiddle is what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/3y2wgsao/14/

css:

```
/* Tabs panel */
.tabbable-panel {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Default mode */
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-left:0; border-right:0; border-top:0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover {


}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a {

  background: none !important;
  border-bottom-color: #fbcdcf;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a > i, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open .dropdown-menu, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a.active {
  border-bottom-color: #f3565d;
  position: relative; display:block;

  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a.active > i {
  color: #404040;
}
.tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.portlet .tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tabbable-panel">
                <div class="tabbable-line">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                            Tab 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                            Tab 2 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                            Tab 3 </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab_default_1" role="tabpanel">
                            <p>
                                I'm in Tab 1.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_default_2" role="tabpanel">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 2.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" target="_blank">
                                    Click for more features...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_default_3" role="tabpanel">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 3.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make bootstrap.js below the jquery.js. check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/3y2wgsao/16/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tabbable-panel">
                <div class="tabbable-line">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 2 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
                            Tab 3 </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
                            <p>
                                I'm in Tab 1.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 2.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Click for more features...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3">
                            <p>
                                Howdy, I'm in Tab 3.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="" target="_blank">
                                    Learn more...
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```